# Where is the golang-1.7 binary?

Tags: software-installation, 16.10, paths, golang

I've installed `golang-1.7` on 16.10, but when I run, e.g. `go version` I get `/usr/bin/go: No such file or directory`.

So I'd like to add the path to `$PATH` so I can use go 1.7, but I don't know where to look for it.

Comment: Did you actually install the `golang` package first? or just `golang-1.7`? The former (or at least, its dependency `golang-go`) is probably responsible for the `/usr/bin/go` symlink

Comment: `golang` installs go 1.6, I did have it installed, but then `go version` gives me version 1.6 which I do not want. So I uninstalled `golang`.   `golang-1.7` has a dependency `golang-1.7-go` which is installed, but which doesn't appear to have produced a symlink in `/usr/bin/go`

Comment: I would suggest leaving `golang` installed (or re-installing it). Then you will likely find that `/usr/bin/go` is a symlink pointing to golang-1.6, which you can then modify either directly or via update-alternatives to point to the corresponding golang-1.7 (instead of modifying `$PATH`)

Comment: That's fair enough, but it doesn't help answer the question that I asked: where *is* the `golang-1.7` binary that I should make the symlink point to.

Comment: Well that should be obvious when you look at where the symlink for 1.6 points - I *think* it's going to be `/usr/lib/go-1.7/bin/go` but I don't have it on my system. See for example  [File list of package golang-1.7-go in yakkety of architecture amd64](http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/amd64/golang-1.7-go/filelist)

Comment: Or, ask your system for the Real Truth: `dpkg -L golang-1.7`

Comment: @waltinator actually, it's `dpkg -L golang-1.7-go`, the other is just a meta package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `golang-1.7-go` binary lives in `/usr/lib/go-1.7/bin/go`

```
$ dpkg -L golang-1.7
/.
/usr
/usr/lib
/usr/lib/go-1.7
/usr/lib/go-1.7/VERSION
/usr/lib/go-1.7/bin
/usr/lib/go-1.7/bin/go
/usr/lib/go-1.7/bin/gofmt
…
```